# How to set the page of print preview when looping data

Tags: html, laravel, print-preview

**This is my print preview page, as you can see the data looping to the next page. How should I do then the data will loop in same page?**

[image]

**For example, the following figure shows the layout I want to do, the data will loop in same page, if full of the page , it will start loop to next page**

[image]

**My Print Page Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>This is a print page!</title>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>
@foreach ($xyprintPreview as $item)
      <h1>{{ $item->xy_sx_ID}}</h1>
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

**New Updated Pic**

[image]

**New Updated Coding**

```
<body>
<table class="report-container" style="width: 100%">
<thead class="report-header">
  <tr>
     <th class="report-header-cell">
        <div class="header-info mt-3">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">
              <img src="https://scontent.fmkz1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/o.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=2&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=gLnsAI4ON1MAX98YpzP&_nc_ht=scontent.fmkz1-1.fna&oh=bacd1bd15cf7a118af57abe52bf7e07e&oe=5FFAAEC0" alt="Avatar" style="width:60px">
              柔佛古庙许愿灯登记名单‎({{$year}}年‎)‎
            </h4>
            <hr style="border: 1px solid;">
                 <b style="margin-left: 180px; font-size: 20px">善信编号&nbsp;&nbsp;名字</b> 
                 <b style="margin-left: 290px; font-size: 20px">善信编号&nbsp;&nbsp;名字</b>
                 <b style="margin-left: 290px; font-size: 20px">善信编号&nbsp;&nbsp;名字</b>   
        </div>
      </th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot class="report-footer">
   <tr>
      <td class="report-footer-cell">
        <div class="footer-info mb-3">
          
        </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody class="report-content ">
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
         <div class="main" style="column-count:3; margin-left: 180px;">
            @foreach($xyprintPreview as $item)
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <span style="font-size: 20px"><b>{{$item->xy_sx_ID}}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$item->xylight_label}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @endforeach
         </div> 
     </td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
```

**Page 2**

[image]

Comment: display them inside <table><tr><td> instead of <h1>, do not add border for table cell

Comment: @4givN It didnt working in `<table>` , still will looping to next page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css property `column-count` can solve your problem.
attach to the div tag enveloping your h1 tags or ul li tags.

```
<div style="column-count: 3;">
</div>
```

It will separate the contents inside this div into three columns with the same page.
YOu can see [demo(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/tonxkbrg/2/)

---

You can use ul, li tag with removing bullet style to none to get ordered results.
You can see [demo(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/tonxkbrg/3/)

Comment: This helpful for my question , now have one more problem was my values didn't  sorting as well

Comment: X00027 is part of li tag?, also by sorting what do you mean sort by number or the alignment is not starting from the same line

Comment: Its like had a space between at the `X00027` and  `X00039` , in my database didn't had any empty data but when the data looping to next page it show perfectly. I have updated the page 2 picture

Comment: there are few things that I consider, first take out ul tag outside of loop, see if it works, If it doesn't then try to add css property `column-width: auto;` to ul tag